# over a million user banking experience persona creation

Tags: user-research, users, personas, banking

I'm working on a banking app project in which I aim to gather user data and put it into a beneficial form in order to make every stakeholder understand quantitatively and qualitatively what's going on, who the users are. I want to update existing personas and I know they will be very broad (I will make narrow personas as I measure the data with the metrics I want to focus on specific areas). My plan is to check data with certain metrics (frequency of tasks, demographics...), research on generic banking personas already available for industry, get insights from customer call center and netnography (app store, forums etc.) then do some qualitative research. What would be your plan? What would be your quanlitative data gathering approach and how would you execute?

Comment: This is a broad question. What specific part of your persona creation project are you struggling with?

Comment: @Nash I haven't started yet, since the number of customers is over a million. I wonder what type of plan you would follow to create personas... (the request/purpose: get to know users of the retail mobile banking app)

Answer (score 1):

That's a totally legitimate question, and usually I start answering with a "trust your guts"

IMO I would go with a back & forth technique depending on the type of data you already have in your hands.

1. With the data you already got, try to isolate schemes or patterns in term of demo like ages, location, maybe types of devices.
2. Do the same with data like: hours of consultation, rhythm of consultation, and type of content.
3. Once you got small groups (I try to limit the max number of group of point 1 and 2 at 10 groups, 20 in total), you need to cross the info to check if demographical info match certain types of habits. You might be able to narrow down to 8 to 12 groups.
4. If you can get qualitative data from customer support I would use them to bring some "hows" or "whats" to the small groups to better evaluate the kind of question I could ask to users.
5. Finally, I'd try to do some user interview with at least 2 persons of each group you "created". The goal would be to gather qualitative data from them to either complete your "group" information, or rework/merge them in smaller groups.

Groups would be represented by your new personae at the end.

To get all those data, I don't know your context, but my reflex would be to ask for:

- a Google Analytics or Matomo, or something similar, to try to extract tendencies. (be critical over the data you find, sometimes the setting is not good and the data can be totally fucked up, I had the case in the past)
- try to gather Apps Review data, Google Review
- try to steal some information from the customer support, they might have some stats on their end.

The first approach of gathering data is to narrow down the stereotype you have of the customers/users to fix your first goals for interviews. Maybe you'll be a bit wrong on this first typical user you have in mind, and that's totally ok. Once you have more information about them, go for a new interpretation of the data, and maybe a second bunch of user interview if you have new questions.

Not sure if I could help you with your question, because I think you kind of get it right since the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answers you will get would be different. I will try to share my view.

First of all, the no of users is going to be huge so I would not be able to rely much on qualitative research. I will try to separate the user's group on the basis of their demographic, education details. I will try to circulate the surveys to a large no. of users. that would give me an understanding of the real users and also that would help stakeholders to understand the users and their needs. after this would try to do user interviews as much as possible to validate the findings from the quantitative methods. This would be the initial research process I will follow.